# Instantiate docker container outside of callee docker container

Tags: java, hadoop, docker

I'm trying to programmatically start up docker containers in my java code that will do some data processing and then die once done.
This is so we don't have loads of docker containers constantly listening on the production cluster.

I have found the docker remote api, which allows me to send http\s calls to do various docker commands. 
I also found a nice library by Spotify that will wrap around these calls.

My questions are:

- If the code calling the remote api is in a docker container, will the container being instantiated in that code live inside the callee docker container? Essentially a docker in a docker.
  This is not ideal as some of the potential containers that will be instantiated by this code will be using tons of RAM, which will exceed the allocated RAM for the callee container, especially if we instantiate n number of containers at any time.
- How could I make the docker container instantiated live alongside the other containers living in the host?
- Are there any things that will need to be done for this to work in a hadoop cluster? The docker api is currently listening to the default unix socket, will this need to be changed to a port for it to work in a cluster?

Docker and Hadoop are new to me, so any information will be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> will the container being instantiated in that code live inside the callee docker container

Where you make the Docker API call from doesn't matter, Containers will be instantiated where the Docker daemon the code is talking to is running. Possibly where you tell the API to run the container if you are using something like Swarm to manage a cluster of Docker hosts.

> Are there any things that will need to be done for this to work in a hadoop cluster?

A Hadoop cluster and Docker (or Docker cluster) are normally managed separately so they are not necessarily the same thing.  Your infrastructure people should be able to tell you how they relate to each other in your environment. How you connect to the Docker API only really changes where your code needs to run rather than what your code can do.